# Javafx Gluon Multiview messenger application view

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

So I want to make a messaging application using gluon. I had a question though. I want to have a login screen each time the user logs in the chat is serverless so it’s basically just to get their name while they use the chat, then I want a view with like all the messages that they can click and it takes them to a secondary view. How do I go about doing this since multiview only has 2 views primary and secondary, and I need 3 views login, main page, and each individual chat. It’s kinda like how Facebook messenger works now. Is it possible to do this using gluon?

Comment: The project that you create with the template has two views, but you can add as many as you want.

Comment: Do you think using gluon mobile is practical for building a messenger app. I already have the code for the backend on desktop, can I just reuse that for the mobile and just redesign the UI?

Comment: I don’t see why not. See this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/comments2.0) for instance, or other similar ones.